# TypeError at /app/accounts/login/ 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable (context_processors.py)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have added the following in my `context_processors.py`

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    recent_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user,is_deleted=False)
else:
    recent_notifications = []


profile = None
if Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

It returns

**TypeError at /app/accounts/login/**

*'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable*

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/accounts/login/?next=/

Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['registration',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'users',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  169.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in __enter__
  81.             return next(self.gen)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in bind_template
  246.             updates.update(processor(self.request))

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/src/cyan/main/context_processors.py" in main_context
  29.     if Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  892.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  910.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1290.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1318.                     split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1224.             self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in check_related_objects
  1086.                 for v in value:

File "/home/cirtic/dev/django/cyan/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  257.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /app/accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

I have tried to change `if request.user.is_authenticated:` into if `request.user.is_authenticated():` as i found in some questions but it returns `'bool' object is not callable`. I'am writing this as this may mistaken as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448624/anonymoususer-object-is-not-iterable)
 Here i have problem with

```
profile = None
if Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        recent_notifications = []
    else:
        recent_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user,is_deleted=False)
```

Otherwise you have to restrict the user by adding login required decorator or similar ways.

Comment: It doesn't works as the problem is not with the  if request.user.is_authenticated: section but with if Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists(): as seen in the traceback

Comment: there you have to restrict the user as login user. use @login_required decorator

Comment: either you can put in a template or use a get or create method, this way profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by editing as follows

```
profile = None
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```